# Stripes Framework expression validation on property

Tags: stripes

I am trying to add expression validation on my property on actionbean but I am unable to make it work. I have even tried with integers like this >0 but still the same exception is thrown. Below is the code

```
 @Validate(required=true, minvalue=1, expression="${this > maxBudget}")
int minBudget;

int maxBudget;
```

I am getting the below exception:

```
 net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesRuntimeException: Could not parse the EL expression being used to validate
  field minBudget. This is not a transient error. Please double check the following expression for errors: ${this > maxBudget}
```

caused by

```
 javax.el.ELException: The identifier [this] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier).
 This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.
```

I have tried few variation, but every time it throws this exception.

Can some one please point out the mistake I am doing here

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure `minBudget` is larger than `maxBudget` (isn't that the other way around?) you could just do:

```
@Validate(required=true, minvalue=1, expression="${minBudget > maxBudget}")
```

For greater flexibility you could consider implementing a custom validation method:

```
@ValidationMethod(on={"show"})
public void checkBudgetRange(ValidationErrors errors) {

    if (minBudget < maxBudget) 
         errors.addGlobalError( new SimpleError("This is not good..."));

    // all sorts of other checks to your liking 
}
```

The `on` array argument holds the name(s) of the event handler(s) for which you want to perform this validation method. So in the example here that would be `public Resolution show()`.

There's an excellent explanation at the Stripes Framework site at https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Validation+Reference

**UPDATE:**
If you want to make use of the `this` keyword in validation expressions you may need to add a VM argument to your server (tested this on Tomcat 8):

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

Otherwise the abovementioned error may be thrown.

The default value of `org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK` was changed from `true` to `false` as of version 7 in Tomcat.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html

Comment: the condition was just for testing purpose, and thanks for the other approach I have already implemented that in other scenarios, But just I wanted to make use of expression validation since it takes less code and I don't have to look up to the validation method to see what validation is done on a particular property. so if you could help me in getting expression validation work that would be really great

Comment: sorry for the above comment, I missed the first line. It is working now, thanks a lot. I still wonder why using `this` was not working as stated in the books and official documentation

Comment: I believe 'this' can only be used in the EL expression in @Validate when the 'field' attribute is also present, but the docs may not be entirely clear about this.

Comment: BTW After some research I must say that you are absolutely right, forget about the previous comment. `@Validate(expression="this=='john'")` should be a valid Validation. I'll update the answer.